# Express middleware after post methodes

Tags: node.js, express

I have a small API build by Angulars Framework Express.
For most of my router I use an auth middleware. But for login or signup the middleware couldn´t work. From my point of knowledge I can do that by hierarchy. But it works only for get methodes:

```
//result: success:true (rcode: 200)
app.get('/test',function(req,res, next){
   res.json({success:true});
}
//result: success:false (rcode: 403)
app.post('/test',function(req,res, next){
   res.json({success:true});
}
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if(token) { ... } else {return res.status(403).send({success:false});}
}
//result: success:false (rcode: 403)
app.get('/test2',function(req,res, next){
   res.json({success:true});
}
```

Does post needs more time and because of nodejs Async architecture the middleware works first or why I get for the post method also response code 403?
And how can I seperate routes with and without middleware?

Comment: You have to call `next` in your route methods on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Create a function for your auth functionality - in this case `authMiddleware`. Use this middleware in all path, that needs this authentication (like the last one in this example)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let authMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body && req.body.token ? req.body.token : (req.query && req.query.token ? req.query.token : req.headers['x-access-token']);
  if (token) {
    // ... your additional code ...
    return next()
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({ success: false });
  }
}

app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ success: true });
})

app.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ success: true });
})

// protected route
app.get('/test2', authMiddleware, function (req, res, next) { 
  res.json({ success: true });
})

app.listen(3000)
```